# Using Behavior in an Open Neighborhood to Prove Invertible Derivative

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset with $f: A \rightarrow
> > \mathbb{R}^n$ being $C^1$ on $A$. Let $x_0 \in A$, and let $Df(x_0)$
> be the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$. Suppose there exists $U$ an open
> neighborhood of $x_0$ and a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in
> U$, $||f(x) - f(y)|| \geq \delta ||x-y||$. Then $Df(x_0)$ is
> invertible.

This question was part of an "if and only" if equivalence. I've already shown that assuming $Df(x_0)$ is invertible gives me the existence of the open neighborhood of $x_0$ with the desired property, but I am stumped on showing this direction that I've described above. I know I can't use Inverse Function Theorem in any way, since that requires $Df(x_0)$ to be invertible and that's what I'm trying to show. What can I try instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $Df(x_0) \cdot h=f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-o(||h||)$ 
 Then, take $x_0=x$ and $x_0+h=y$ and you have that $Df(x) \cdot h+o(||h||)=f(y)-f(x)$.  Now take the norm in both sides. You get $||Df(x) \cdot h+o(||h||)||=||f(y)-f(x)||$. 
 A little oh function of ||h|| is some function that, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\phi$ s.t it  has its norm smaller than $\epsilon ||h||$, for $||h|| \lt \phi$. We might take this $\phi$ radius open ball to be contained in the neighborhood.  As such, by the triangle inequality, the lhs is smaller than $||Df(x) \cdot h|+||o(||h||)|| \leq||Df(x) \cdot h||+\epsilon ||h||=||Df(x) \cdot (y-x)||+\epsilon ||y-x||$. But, on the other hand, we know from assumption that the right handside is bigger than $\delta ||y-x||$, for some $\delta$. 
So, we have that $||Df(x) \cdot (y-x)||+\epsilon ||y-x|| \geq \delta ||y-x||$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: So, essentially what you're showing is that $||Df(x) \cdot (y-x)|| \geq \delta ||y-x||$, correct? What does this imply about the invertibility of $Df(x_0)$?

Comment: @maths if $||Df(x) \cdot (y-x) ||\geq \delta ||y-x||$, suppose that $Df \cdot v=Df \cdot u$ for two different vector $u,v$. Then,$ ||Df \cdot (v-u)|| \geq \delta ||v-u|| $ But the lhs is zero by assumption, so that must mean v and u are equal (i.e $Df$ is injective). Then by the rank-nullity theorem (because the image of $Df$ is bounded inferiorly, the dimension of the kernel must be zero and the dimension of the image is then n), $Df$ is also surjective, and as such it is invertible.